# Unpacking an array of records/fields in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Having trouble unpacking an array that is generated by rails. The array looks okay and makes sense, but unpacking it doesn't.

**Here is the ruby code I have written to test it:**

```
assets = {"0"=>{"id"=>"1", "add_asset"=>"0"},
          "1"=>{"id"=>"2", "add_asset"=>"0"},
          "2"=>{"id"=>"3", "add_asset"=>"1"}}

puts "assets= " + assets.to_s
puts "size = " + assets.length.to_s
assets.each_with_index do |check, i|
  puts "--i = " + i.to_s
  this = check[i]
  puts "this = " + this.to_s
  puts "id = " + this["id"].to_s
  puts "add = " + this["add_asset"].to_s
end
```

**And here is the result I am getting:**

*d:\Users\Michael\Documents>ruby test.rb*

```
assets= {"0"=>{"id"=>"1", "add_asset"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2", "add_asset"=>"0"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"3", "add_asset"=>"1"}}
size = 3
--i = 0
this = 0
id =
add =
--i = 1
this = {"id"=>"2", "add_asset"=>"0"}
id = 2
add = 0
--i = 2
this =
test.rb:14:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:10:in `each'
    from test.rb:10:in `each_with_index'
    from test.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is it failing to read record "0" then successfully reading record "1"?
2. Why is it bombing completely on record "2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby there is a difference between a hash and an array. Hashes can have nearly anything as a key. An array accepts only an integer. Your hashes are built with strings for keys.  Decompose like this:

```
assets = {"0"=>{"id"=>"1", "add_asset"=>"0"},
          "1"=>{"id"=>"2", "add_asset"=>"0"},
          "2"=>{"id"=>"3", "add_asset"=>"1"}}

assets.each do |key, val|
  puts "key = #{key}"
  val.each do |inner_key, inner_val|
    puts "  key=#{inner_key} val=#{inner_val}"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
key = 0
  key=id val=1
  key=add_asset val=0
key = 1
  key=id val=2
  key=add_asset val=0
key = 2
  key=id val=3
  key=add_asset val=1
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `each_with_index`. You're iterating over a hash, not an array. To iterate over the keys and values of a hash, use `hash.each |key,value|`.

`each_with_index` converts your hash to an array, in the form `[ [key1, value1], [key2, value2], ...]`. This will give you something that looks like this:

```
[
  ["0", {"id"=>"1", "add_asset"=>"0"}],
  ["1", {"id"=>"2", "add_asset"=>"0"}],
  ["2", {"id"=>"3", "add_asset"=>"1"}]
]
```

So:

> Why is it failing to read record "0" then successfully reading record "1"?

It isn't. It's failing all three times, it's just one failure happens to look correct.

The first iteration, `i` is 0 and `check` is equal to `["0", {"id"=>"1", "add_asset"=>"0"}]`, your block accesses `check[0]` which is `"0"`. You then check `"0"["id"]` and `"0"["add_asset"]`, which are both `nil`.

On the next iteration, `i` is `1` and `check` is `["1", {"id"=>"2", "add_asset"=>"0"}]`. The block accesses `check[1]` and gets `{"id"=>"2", "add_asset"=>"0"}` purely by coincidence, and things seem to work.

> Why is it bombing completely on record "2"?

On the third iteration, the block gets an `i` of `2` and `check` of `["2", {"id"=>"3", "add_asset"=>"1"}]`. That array has no `[2]`, so you get `nil`, and then your block attempts to access `nil["add"]` which fails.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to rails after years in databases and many languages. Still good to learn something new!